# Seeking clarification on the rules in regards to perceived privacy violation

Tags: discussion

Very simply put, I wish to express my feelings about a situation that has occurred here, regarding this: [Rejecting an invite to a work social event whilst perceived working situation is currently untenable](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/187685/rejecting-an-invite-to-a-work-social-event-whilst-perceived-working-situation-is)

1. I made a post, very very much regret making it - the level of detail contained within it is something I didn't consider at the time to be something I could be easily identified from, but I'm very aware on reflection that's the case. I divulged some information that was shared with me only, and there is some information in that post that would get me in a lot of trouble as it was information that was only supposed to be shared with me. In the interest of giving better context, I left all of that in but now see that as a huge mistake.
2. I received some answers, out of courtesy I did the right thing and marked the one answer I got as helpful. I edited the post out, and wiped out the text until such a time as I could either get it into a position where it would be watered down and removed of any context that would make it very clear who I was. I would say that probably up to a dozen people would be able to find that post and make the connection, at least six of those people actively use this site.
3. Kate Gregory reinstated the post against my wishes. I edited out the post again, it was reinstated and I have been blocked from being able to edit it further.

I'm going to be calling ICO (the national information rights organisation in my country) as soon as it opens in the morning and seeking further guidance on what my rights are, as I'm very aware at this point that having my opportunity to remove something from the internet that I don't want to be there, is a massive, flagrant abuse of GDPR in my country and, in the kindest terms possible, I'd like to ask you to revert your mistake because that's exactly what it is. If it has been felt that this has circumvented the purity of your platform here, and that these posts are supposed to stay up indefinitely so they can be referred to for years to come, I apologise wholeheartedly for that but I believe you're breaking the law by refusing my right of control over the content I have posted.

Remove it please. On this specific platform, I won't ask you again but will go over your heads instead if I have to.

Comment: You want to know your rights as an anonymous poster in a public forum because somehow you think this is GDPR abuse? Wouldn't it be easier to ask the Mods nicely to delete you entirely from the system rather than threatening them?

Comment: The fault of venting your frustrations and revealing details of your rapport with  superiors etc is yours and yours alone. You had the time to delete the question before receiving an answer. Accepting it and then immediately deleting the question was rude to the answerer. Your last hope is to politely ask the user, whose answer you accepted, to delete their own post and then delete your question (though there's the slight chance the mods might undelete both posts). There is no obligation for the user to delete their answer, but 50 points is not such a big deal, so they just might.

Comment: “Accepting it and then immediately deleting the **content of the question was rude …”

Answer (score 15):

> I made a post, very very much regret making it - the level of detail contained within it is something I didn't consider at the time to be something I could be easily identified from, but I'm very aware on reflection that's the case. I divulged some information that was shared with me only, and there is some information in that post that would get me in a lot of trouble as it was information that was only supposed to be shared with me. In the interest of giving better context, I left all of that in but now see that as a huge mistake.

When you post something to a Stack Exchange site it is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)), as described in the network ToS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing), vandalising your posts in an attempt to destroy this content goes contrary to this and I'm afraid personal regret about posting doesn't change that fact.

> I received some answers, out of courtesy I did the right thing and marked the one answer I got as helpful. I edited the post out, and wiped out the text until such a time as I could either get it into a position where it would be watered down and removed of any context that would make it very clear who I was. I would say that probably up to a dozen people would be able to find that post and make the connection, at least six of those people actively use this site.

I locked the post - this is standard SE practice in the event of post vandalism/edit wars. I'm not insensitive to your concerns however, and if you can provide a version of the question that removes the content you're concerned about while not invalidating the answer then you can drop a mod flag on the question when you are ready to edit and I'll remove the content lock.

> I'm going to be calling ICO (the national information rights organisation in my country) as soon as it opens in the morning and seeking further guidance on what my rights are, as I'm very aware at this point that having my opportunity to remove something from the internet that I don't want to be there, is a massive, flagrant abuse of GDPR in my country and, in the kindest terms possible, I'd like to ask you to revert your mistake because that's exactly what it is. If it has been felt that this has circumvented the purity of your platform here, and that these posts are supposed to stay up indefinitely so they can be referred to for years to come, I apologise wholeheartedly for that but I believe you're breaking the law by refusing my right of control over the content I have posted.

Questions and Answers remaining up as future reference material for "years to come" **is** central to the ethos of the Stack Exchange network - which is why steps will be taken to counter destructive edits of this type. You are of course free to contact the ICO or [Stack Exchange themselves](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/contact) but I have to say I'm struggling to see where there are GDPR implications here - there's no PII in your post (either yours or anyone else's) and as mentioned above when you posted here you licensed the content of the post to SE and that comes with a loss of control over what happens to it afterwards.

Comment: That makes it quite predatory then, in my opinion.

Comment: Absolutely not happy at you for removing my right to amend my own content if I feel it's going to get me in trouble. Really honestly not interested if the two of you that have posted here, don't agree with me. It doesn't matter what you think, it matters what I think and I believe it's identification that can easily identify me if the wrong person comes across it. It would also quite negatively adversely affect my position too, but that quite clearly doesn't matter to you. Internet points do.

Comment: I've gotten in touch with ICO (the national privacy rights organisation in my country) and will be going over your heads. What you're doing is extremely low-quality and insensitive, and I won't stop until that post is gone entirely from this site. That is my right, and it goes beyond some silly content rules you've set here.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. No one bears you any malice. But this site is not about an individuals beliefs although we do try to cater to individuals. In this case if it hadn't had an upvoted answer which was accepted I might have deleted the whole question. Although with reluctance because many well meaning individuals spent the time to read through your problem in hopes of helping you. But since it has and in my judgement does not pose a significant identity threat, I suggest again that you remove any personal identity information you imagine is in the post. I don't see the need for drama.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a non problem. I have read the question twice, quite a missive, and fail to see how it couldn't apply to lots of people rather than pinpoint you. I don't see anything except generic information.

One thing about unsavoury team leads or colleagues is they don't view themselves as unsavoury so would be unlikely to connect themselves with a story about one.

I'd advise you respectfully not to worry about it unduly. If you do see anything that pinpoints you that I have missed, then edit it out. Realistically most of the background could dissappear and still leave the basic question intact.

As far as legal action, I'm not a lawyer, but site policy as mentioned in Moto's answer is usually to retain the question for reference. Especially if it has an accepted answer as it indicates volunteers have spent time and effort giving useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

> as I'm very aware at this point that having my opportunity to remove something from the internet that I don't want to be there, is a massive, flagrant abuse of GDPR in my country

No, it's not. The GDPR is not about removing things from the internet you don't want there. That is a misunderstanding of both the target and intent of the GDPR. The GDPR protects your personal data, whether *you* posted them or someone else:

> ‘Personal data’ means any information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person (‘data subject’); an identifiable natural person is one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, an identification number, location data, an online identifier or to one or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic, mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person.

[Source](https://gdpr.eu/eu-gdpr-personal-data/)

So if you had for example, accidentially posted your name, you bosses name, your email or company name, licence plate, *anything* where one could without fail point a finger and say "it's *them*", that would indeed be covered by the GDPR. A story, that if enough people guess who it was written by, sooner or later one will be correct, is not "personally identifyable information".

Your post is generic. So generic, I read it again and after half of it, I can confidently say: at another time in my life, that was me. You absolutely described the company and my role in it. It is in no way unique. Shitty companies exist a dime a dozen, shitty people are even more common.

So, there is no protection rooted in the GDPR here. There is no specific PII to be removed.

That said, even before the GDPR, everybody here understood the need for anonymity, and mistakes like not obfuscating names have always been rectified without problems.

The problem is deleting your whole post. You signed a TOS that allows SE to show your post. This is how SE makes it's money. The fact that you got free advice here is partly due to the fact that the server owners reserve the right to have the question and answer found via search engines and show ads to people finding them. That is how they make money to keep this site running and allowing you and me to write things here. This publicity is the price you pay for "free" advice.

So if you get your "free" advice, but later decide that you aren't willing to pay the price you agreed to pay, that is seen very negatively by most people.

---

So how to go from here? You can go to the ICO. Personally, I would encourage you to do so. Never trust random strangers from the internet. In other words: let them verify what I wrote about the GDPR here. It won't get you anywhere, but it will educate you about your rights (and where they end). Education is always good.

But then what? Well, again, we do not object to making your question less specific. For example, your post contains specifics as in someone leaving in December. That is not GDPR relevant, it's not even *your* data, strictly speaking it's theirs. So even if it were PII, it would not be yours to remove. But it is also not very relevant to the question. Just edit that into "in a few months". One less very specific detail to worry about, and nothing lost in regards to keeping the question intact.

If you are worried to be found out, edit out the small details that you think will make people think of you specifically. The general question is sadly *very* common and in no way identifies you directly any more than thousands of other people.